# Silverlight 4.0: DataGridTextColumn Name

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, datagrid

Is there a way to get the `DataGridTextColumn` name in code behind? For example: I want to get `Database` name value:

```
<sdk:DataGrid  AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
        <sdk:DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Database">
            </sdk:DataGridTextColumn>
        </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
    </sdk:DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```
var columnName = myDataGrid.Columns[0].GetValue(FrameworkElement.NameProperty);
```

or if it is inside of the page:

```
var columnName = myDataGrid.Columns[0].GetValue(NameProperty);
```

I assumed that you know index. Because if both name and index are unknown, it would be difficult to find it :), unless there are other distinctive properties.

Comment: Thanks! Been thinking of it for almost an hour